# If Clojure data structures are immutable, then what makes it memory efficient?

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, if the data structures are immutable, then it means that it returns a new variable if we apply try to change the data.

Now, this new variable will take up some memory.

How is such an architecture an efficient one?

For example, if I am changing a value of a variable inside a loop, then it will create many variables (new one per iteration of the loop) and the thread's stack might overflow.

Comment: You are not "changing a value of a variable in a loop", you are reassigning a different, immutable, value at each iteration to the same name (Var). Nothing special should happen in terms of memory (heap, not stack). The magic actually happens when dealing with aggregate types, like lists and maps. Check out HAMT to see how memory (and time) are kept to a minimum while still providing immutable guaranties.

Answer (score 3):

When a Clojure Var is rebound to a new value, it no longer references the old value. If there are no other references to the old value, it will become eligible for garbage collection.

There are many Clojure functions which accept a collection value and return a new derived value:

```clj
(def xs [:a :b :c])
(def ys (conj xs :d))     ; => [:a :b :c :d]
```

Rather than naïvely copy the contents of `xs` to build `ys`, Clojure uses [persistent data structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) to build the values incrementally. This technique employs *data sharing* to enable efficient creation of new values (in terms of both memory and time), while preserving old values.